# Java application /proc/${pid}/fd found many files with broken symlinks

Tags: java, linux, sockets

[image]

As above, I find **thounds** of socket undereath the `/pro/${pid}/fd`  directory, and I checked active opened files amount was about 100, I tried to use the broken socket's inode number to `grep` the `/proc/net/` directory, nothing matches.

How can I find what's holding the file descriptors?

Appreciate any attempt!